# What is the equivalent of utf8-sig in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to find the equivalent of utf-8-sig in pyspark.

If my file contains headers, it cannot be read anymore with utf-8 (i don't know why).

I've tried utf-8-sig `.option("encoding", "utf-8-sig")` but get the following error :

> java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: utf-8-sig

It works with utf-16, but sometimes the file contains headers, sometimes not. So i would prefer a dynamic solution.

Is there any equivalent to utf-8-sig?

Comment: `utf-8-sig` is the name *Python* gives to UTF8 with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). That's just 3 bytes at the start of the file that mark it as a UTF8-encoded text file. The rest of the file is UTF8. You could strip those 3 bytes and the file would work with every application that expects UTF8. Why not use just `UTF-8` ? Do you really need the BOM?

Comment: I had the same problem and in my case the default encoding 'UTF-8' worked to  read files that contain a BOM. But all my files hat headers so the case is different than yours.